# Grabbing array-like data via SQL joins to form complete object

Tags: sql, postgresql, node-postgres

I have the following three tables:

`drinks: id | name`

`ingredient: id | name`

`drink_ingredients: drinks.id | ingredients.id`

When I create a "drink", I provide an array of ingredient ids as well. The relationship here is managed by the `drink_ingredients` table, which allows me to reuse ingredients.

I'm trying to create a query of which will return data representing the following:

`drink { id: 0 | name: 'Coffee' | ingredients: [2, 3] }`

Essentially meaning I would like to extract out the ingredient id attached to this drink and return them as an array.

I currently have

`select * from "drinks" inner join "drink_ingredients" on "drinks"."id" = "drink_ingredients"."drink_id"`

I'm still missing the step to retrieve the data from `ingredients`, but as well this, this returns:

```
  {
    "id": 0,
    "owner": 18,
    "name": "Coffee",
    "drink_id": 0,
    "ingredient_id": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 0,
    "owner": 18,
    "name": "Coffee",
    "drink_id": 0,
    "ingredient_id": 3
  },
```

Is it possible to correctly embed data this way in a single statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using the `array_agg` function:

```
select d.id, d.name, array_agg(di.ingredient_id) as ingredients
from drinks d
  left outer join drink_ingredients di on di.drink_id = d.id
group by d.id, d.name
```

As you (per your question) only want the array of ingredient-ids, you don't even need to join with ingredients. The left join is just in case you have a drink with no ingredients (water?).

Comment: I dreamed bigger and managed to get the JSON representation of my objects in their complete form rather than IDs. Your help on the join was what got me there, thanks very much for your assistance and concise answer!